# BASH reading txt file and storing in array

Tags: bash, files, array

I'm writing my first BASH script , I have some experience with c and c# so I think the logic of the program is correct..it's just the syntax is so complicated because apparently there are billions of ways to write the same thing!

Anyway here is the script: it simply checks if the argument (string) is contained in a certain file . If so it stores each line of the file in an array and writes an item of the array in a file. I'm sure there must be easier ways to achieve that but I want to do some practice with bash loops

```
    #!/bin/bash

NOME=$1
c=0


#IF NAME IS FOUND IN THE PHONEBOOK THANK STORE EACH LINE OF THE FILE INTO ARRAY
#ONCE THE ARRAY IS DONE GET THE INDEX OF MATCHING NAME AND RETURN ARRAY[INDEX+1]

if grep  "$NOME" /root/phonebook.txt ; then
        echo "CREATING ARRAY"
        while read line
        do
                myArray[$c]=$line # store line
                c=$(expr $c + 1) # increase counter by 1
        done < /root/phonebook.txt

else
        echo "Name not found"
fi

c=0
for i in myArray;
        do
              if   myArray[$i]="$NOME" ;  then
                 echo ${myArray[i+1]} >> /root/numbertocall.txt
              fi

done
```

This code does returns the only the second item of myArray (`myArray[2]` or the second line of the file)..why?

Comment: What relevance has the \t? Both the text and the rest of the code just refer to lines.

Comment: Not a direct answer, so it's just a comment, but I'd do this with one a one liner grep; `grep -P -o "(?<=$NOME\t).+"`

Comment: @Patrick Classic [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), so I think your comment should be an answer. It does the right thing after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
IFS=$'\n' a=($(cat phonebook.txt))
for i in $(seq ${#a[*]}); do
    [[ ${a[$i-1]} = $name ]] && echo "${a[$i]}"
done
```

In Bash 4 `IFS=$'\n' a=($(cat phonebook.txt))` can be replaced with `mapfile -t a < phonebook.txt`.

grep -A1 prints one line after the match. -x disables regex like -F but it only matches complete lines.

```
grep -x "$name" -A1 phonebook.txt | tail -n1
```

Comment: You *may* want to validate the contents of the file first.  Up to you.

Comment: `-x` does not *disable regex*.

Comment: Leaving that `$(cat phonebook.txt)` unquoted in that list context invokes split+glob on the expansion. Here, you want the *split* part, but not the *glob* part, so it should be disabled (`set -o noglob`).

Comment: It should be `grep -xFe "$name" -A1 phonebook.txt` or `grep -xFA1 -- "$name" phonebook.txt` or it won't work properly if `$name` starts with `-` or `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment.

Comment: In `bash`, it's either `[[ $string = $pattern ]]` or `[[ $string = "$otherstring" ]]`. Or IOW, you need to quote word expansions on the right hand side of the `=` operator inside `[[...]]` if you don't want it to be taken as a pattern.

Comment: To loop of the indices of an array in bash, it's `for i in "${!a[@]}"`. For non-sparse arrays, you can also do `for ((i = 0; i < ${#a[@]}; i++))` which would be equivalent to your `seq` based one except it doesn't rely on the availability of the non-standard `seq` command and avoids storing the whole output of that seq command several times in memory and making assumptions on the current value of `$IFS`.

Answer (score 2):

```
index=0
while read line; do
  myArray[index]="$line"
done < inputfile
```

Newer versions of bash support associative arrays. That would make it easier:

```
declare -A myArray
while read name; do
  read number
  myArray[name]="$number"
done < inputfile

echo ${myArray[name]}
```

Comment: and how would you return the item of myArray[name + 1] ?

Comment: In the indexed example you already had the solution thus I didn't copy it.

Comment: May I be wrong, but using such pipe would not make myArray "invisible" to outside of loop???

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez Neither the question nor my answer contains a pipeline thus I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: "while read name;" looks to me like a pipeline, anyway, i found the "declare -a array" fixes troubles i got before, thanks!!! +1

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez `while read name` is a loop, not a pipeline. `cmd1 | cmd2` is a pipeline. `while read name` is often used with a pipeline, though. But in this case it gets its input from redirection. Redirection is often used to get around the pipeline problems with variables.

Comment: These answers are wrong, as they fail to increment the index.

Comment: The `bash` syntax to read a line of input into a variable is `IFS= read -r line`, not `read line`

Answer (score 2):

In a question titled "*BASH reading txt file and storing in array*" I feel `readarray` deserves a mention. An example of this method I use to read test files into an array would be:

```
readarray -t arrayIPblacklist < /etc/postfix/IP-black-list.txt
```

The foregoing loads a file of IP addresses- separated by newlines- into an array called "*arrayIPblacklist*". Would work on your phonebook file. `readarray` was introduced in bash 4, so this method won't work on older hosts running earlier bash versions.

The `-t` option strips the newline delimiters from each element, as most of the time you don't want them included.

```
$ seq 3 | bash -c 'readarray a; printf "<%q>\n" "${a[@]}"'
<$'1\n'>
<$'2\n'>
<$'3\n'>
$ seq 3 | bash -c 'readarray -t a; printf "<%q>\n" "${a[@]}"'
<1>
<2>
<3>
```

Comment: Note that the accepted answer already mentioned `mapfile` which is another (albeit more confusing) name for the `readarray` builtin.

Comment: My bad- didn't see that.  Thanks @StéphaneChazelas !